# Populating the AJAX url in a JSTree with model information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

I am populating a JSTree view with ajax commands.  My current JS code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#navigation").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": function (node) {
                        var nodeId = "";
                        var url = "";
                        if (node == -1) {
                            url = "@Url.Action("BaseTreeItems", "Events")";
                        } else {
                            nodeId = node.attr('id');
                            url = "@Url.Action("EventTreeItems", "Events")" +"?selectedYear=" + nodeId;
                        }
                        return url;
                    },
                    "dataType": "text json",
                    "contentType": "application/json charset=utf-8",
                    "data": function(n) { return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 }; },
                    "success": function() {
                    }
                }
            },
            "themes": {
                "theme": "classic"
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]
        });
    });
```

I would like to eliminate the if statement from the "ajax" property and fill it with the JSON data that is coming from the server.  The JSON data looks like this

```
[{"data":{"title":"2012","attr":{"href":"/Events/EventList?selectedYear=2012"}},"attr":{"id":"2012","selected":false,"ajax":"/Events/EventTreeItems?selectedYear=2012"},"children":null,"state":"closed"},.....]
```

How can I feed the "ajax" property from the json into the "ajax" property in the JSTree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference I fixed it by doing the following

```
.jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": function (node) {
                        var url;
                        if (node == -1) {
                            url = "@Url.Action("BaseTreeItems", "Events")";
                        } else {
                            url = node.attr('ajax');
                        }
                        return url;
                    },
                    "dataType": "text json",
                    "contentType": "application/json charset=utf-8",
                    "data": function(n) { return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0, ajax: n.attr ? n.attr("ajax") : 0 }; },
                    "success": function() {
                    }
                }
            },
```